# how to import sibling files from a script

Tags: python-3.x, import, package

I am aware there is plenty of similar questions out there. But trust me I have tried a lot of things but I don't know why they are not working for me. So I just want a step-by-step answer to approach this problem

I just created a representation of my files structure to reduce complexity and easy to duplicate for testing

```bash
imp
├── __init__.py
├── app1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── func1.py
└── app2
    └── func2.py
```

inside func1.py

```py
def hello():
    print("Hello there!")
```

and inside func2.py

```py
from app1 import func1

func1.hello()
```

Now I mainly want to run `func2.py` from the root directory i.e, `imp/`. And if possible I want to make it executable from its own folder i.e, `imp/app2/`

what I tried

- added **init**.py
- tried relative import
- tried appending and inserting path

  - `sys.path.append('..')` in func2.py
  - `sys.path.insert(0, '..')` in func2.py

none of them worked, I don't know what I am missing.

PS: Btw I am using python 3. Also, I prefer a solution without editing path (as it is not considered to good practise)

Comment: There is no module called `func2` in `app1`. Did you mean `func1`?

Comment: yeah sorry, let me fix that